# concising the Codes in R

Tags: r

I want to turn these codes into one .  For every person in my data set, I have 31 probabilities  and based on them, I want to know if they migrate by the end of the year or not. These codes work, but I want them to be concise and practical for data with more districts.

```r
ifelse  ((survival1a$district==1)  ,sample(0:30, size=2000, replace=TRUE ,prob= c(Migdata$`1`)),
                         
 ifelse  ((survival1a$district==2)  ,sample(0:30, size=2000, replace=TRUE ,prob= c(Migdata$`2`)),
                         
 ifelse  ((survival1a$district==3)  ,sample(0:30, size=2000, replace=TRUE ,prob= c(Migdata$`3`)),
                        
  ifelse  ((survival1a$district==4)  ,sample(0:30, size=2000, replace=TRUE ,prob= c(Migdata$`4`)),
                       
ifelse  ((survival1a$district==5)  ,sample(0:30, size=2000, replace=TRUE ,prob= c(Migdata$`5`)),
                         
 ifelse  ((survival1a$district==6)  ,sample(0:30, size=2000, replace=TRUE ,prob= c(Migdata$`6`)),
                        
 ifelse  ((survival1a$district==7)  ,sample(0:30, size=2000, replace=TRUE ,prob= c(Migdata$`7`)),
                          
ifelse  ((survival1a$district==8)  ,sample(0:30, size=2000, replace=TRUE ,prob= c(Migdata$`8`)),
                     
ifelse  ((survival1a$district==9)  ,sample(0:30, size=2000, replace=TRUE ,prob= c(Migdata$`9`)),
...
```

Comment: I have a doubt in the comment.  Are you creating a single column 'district' on 'migration' and can you specify the number of rows of 'migration' data

Comment: @akrun 
I want to create a single column district on migration. In fact, based on 31 probabilities, I would like to know where a person after one year will migrate. Migdata is a matrich with 31 rows and 31 columns showing the probabilities of migration from one district to another district.

Comment: Do you have 2000 rows in migration data? Whether it is the same number of rows as 'survival1a'

Comment: @akurn
I wrote this and it works but it is so time-consuming:
    for (k in 1:nrow(survival1a)){
      survival1a$district[k]<-
        sample(0:30, size=1,replace = TRUE,prob=migdata[k,2:31])
    }

Comment: @akrun
I have some individuals from 31 different districts (here 2000 and the file name is survival1a) and I have a matrix for probabilities of migration from one district to other(Migdata)

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: SAMPLE = function( PROB ){
             return( sample(0:30, size=1,replace = TRUE,prob=PROB) )
           }
           survival1a$migrant<-  apply(survival1a[,3:33] , 1 , SAMPLE )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SAMPLE = function( PROB ){return( sample(0:30, size=1,replace = TRUE, prob=PROB))
}
survival1a$migrant<-  apply(survival1a[,3:33] , 1 , SAMPLE )
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `split` i.e. `split` the 'district' column by the same column, loop over the `list`, get the `sample` of 0 to 30 with `size` specified as `length` of that `list` element, and `prob` as the column selected from 'Migdata'

```
migration$district <- unsplit(lapply(split(survival1a$district, 
  survival1a$district, drop = TRUE), 
       function(i)  sample(0:30, size= length(i), replace=TRUE, 
        prob= Migdata[[i[1]]])), survival1a$district)
```

Comment: Error in .subset2(x, i) : 
  attempt to select less than one element in integerOneIndex
Called from: `[[.tbl_df`(Migdata, i[1])

Comment: @MohammadHaddadi I assume that all the district unique values are the column names of 'Migdata'

Comment: @MohammadHaddadi try with `drop = TRUE` (in the updated code)

Comment: When I merge my matrix, which is the migration probabilities with my data(survival1a), I have  2000 individuals for each of whom I have 31 probabilities. each probability shows the likelihood of migration to other districts or staying in the same district as before. I would like to know by the end of the year each individual's new district code.

Comment: @MohammadHaddadi It is better to post with a small reproducible example for testing.  Without that, the code is just based on your code in the post

Comment: @ akrun
How I can write the below code without loop?
 for (k in 1:nrow(survival1a)){
     survival1a$migration[k]<-
        sample(0:30, size=1,replace = TRUE,prob=survival1a[k,7:37])
    }

Comment: @MohammadHaddadi Instead of `1:nrow` I would suggest `for(k in unique(survival1a$district))` and subset the rows as showed in my split

Comment: Dear Arun Kirshna
@akrun
I would really appreciate it if you can help me with this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/q/66663638/15398802?sem=2