# How alter R codes in efficient way

Tags: r

I have a sample created as follows:

```
    survival1a= data.frame(matrix(vector(), 50, 2,dimnames=list(c(), c("Id", "district"))),stringsAsFactors=F)


    survival1a$Id <- 1:nrow(survival1a)


    survival1a$district<- sample(1:4, size=50, replace=TRUE)
```

this sample has 50 individuals from 4 different districts.

I have probabilities (a matrix) that shows the likelihood of migration from one district to another(Migdata) as follows:

district*****       prob1******      prob2********       prob3*******  prob4**

1. ```
       0.83790    0.08674      0.05524    0.02014
   ```
2. ```
       0.02184    0.88260      0.03368    0.06191
   ```
3. ```
       0.01093    0.03565      0.91000    0.04344
   ```
4. ```
       0.03338    0.06933      0.03644    0.86090
   ```

---

I merge these probabilities with my data with this code:

```
    survival1a<-merge( Migdata,survival1a, by.x=c("district"), by.y=c("district"))
```

I would like to know by the end of the year each person resides in which districts based on probabilities of migration that I have(Migdata).

I have already written a code that perfectly works but with big data it is so time-consuming since it is based on a Loop:

```
for (k in 1:nrow(survival1a)){
  survival1a$migration[k]<-sample(1:4, size=1,replace = TRUE,prob=survival1a[k,2:5])}
```

Now, I want to write the code in a way that it would not be based on a loop and shows every person district by the end of the year.

Comment: @akrun
This is a reproducible example from my data.

Comment: @Ronak Shah
This is a reproducible example from my data.

Comment: I don't think you can really avoid loop of some sort since the probability is different for every individual. You need to use a `for` loop or one of the `apply` commands.

Comment: @RonakShah     How I can use apply commands to rewrite the above-mentioned command?" Since my data is so big, time is so important for me. The loop is so time-consuming.